# Compare two custom objects in java with nullable fields

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, collections, null

I have a `Collection<A>`

```
class A {
    String name;
    Long id;
}
```

Now I have UI screen where I can provide name & id value to match this collection and display the result.

Now I have 3 criteria:

1. Only Id provided: Display all the records matchs with Id although name is null
2. Only name
3. Both Name and Id.

I can do it by three `if` check-based on null check of UI fields but I don't want to make `if-else` block because if I have multiple UI fileds it would be hectic to do nested `if-else` check.

Please suggest a better way in java 7.

Comment: override equals.

Comment: I could not because if i can have same name for two people and if i provide only name in UI ,it should provide two records

Comment: The only way i see to solve this is to use predicates based code. But you still have to check each UI filed to see if you should include it in creterias or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide some predicates that are used to filter the collection. Since `java.util.function.Predicate` has only been added with Java 8 you'd need to either roll your own or use a library such as [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

With that you could pass the predicates to be used in a filter:

```
Collection<Predicate<A>> predicates = ...;//you get them from your UI
Collection<A> filtered = Collections2.filter( originalCollection, Preciates.and( predicates ) );
```

The predicates could then look like this:

```
class ANamePredicate implements Predicate<A> {
  private String name; 

  public ANamePredicate( String n) { 
    name = n;
  }     

  boolean apply(@Nullable A input) { 
    //if one or both could be null, add handling for that
    return input.name.equals(n);
  }

  //implement equals(...) as well
}
```

Of course you could use anonymous classes as well but you'd then probably want to provide for an abstract base class that remove the requirement to always implement `equals()`:

```
abstract class AbstractPredicate<T> implements Predicate<T> {
  public boolean equals( Object o) { 
    //simplified, you might have to provide a better implementation, e.g. you want to provide a set of predicates
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then you create a collection of predicates when needed:

```
Collection<Predicate<A>> predicates = new LinkedList<>();
predicates.add( new AbstractPredicate<A>() {
   boolean apply(A input) { 
    return "Skabdus".equals(input.name);
   }
} );
predicates.add( new AbstractPredicate<A>() {
   boolean apply(A input) { 
    return input.id == 1;
   }
} );
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the code snippet.It will be better for me specially predicates one

Comment: @Skabdus I added a simplified exemplary implementation of such a predicate. Is that the elaboration you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **decorator pattern** with expressions. The principle is to have an interface that each "criteria" will implement (with one method : eval) and to have a distinction bewteen **terminal operators** and **not terminal operators**.

You would have a **NameIsSet** class, an **IdIsSet** class as terminal opeators (or other classes if you have other implementations in the future), and logical expressions as non-terminal operators : **And**, **Or**, **Not**, ...

Then, you should use the pattern this way :

```
Predicate predicate = new And(new IdIsSet("id"), new Not(new NameIsSet("name")));
if(predicate.eval()){
// Do something
}
```

If you want to set a particular behaviour for each case, you could create a List of these predicates and set a method to call if the predicate is true :

```
for(Predicate predicate: predicateList){
    if(predicate.eval()) {
       predicate.execute();
       //break if only one case is accepted
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of And class and NameIsSet class:

```
public class And implements Predicate{
    private Predicate pred1;
    private Predicate pred2;

    public And(Predicate p1, Predicate p2){
        this.pred1 = p1;
        this.pred2 = p2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean eval(){
        return this.pred1.eval() && this.pred2.eval();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(){
        // Not sure of you want to do here
    }

}

public class NameIsSet implements Predicate{
    private String name;

    public NameIsSet (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean eval(){
        return this.name == null || this.name.length = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(){
        // Not sure of you want to do here
    }

}
```

In this implementation, you must create all your predicates beforehand, add them to a list and set the execute() method for each.

Hope this will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements don't need to be nested. You can, for example, do this:

```
static boolean matches(A candidate, A pattern) {
    if (pattern.name != null && !candidate.name.equals(pattern.name))
        return false;
    if (pattern.id != null && !candidate.id.equals(pattern.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

This scales at a 1:1 rate with any number of fields. (You could use `candidate.id != pattern.id` there, but I used `equals` for consistency.)

If you have dozens of fields and you don't want to name them individually, you can use reflection and process all the fields with a single `for` loop:

```
static boolean matches(A candidate, A pattern) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field fld : A.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        Object c = fld.get(candidate);
        Object p = fld.get(pattern);
        if (p != null && !c.equals(p))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```